# Is anonymous credentials in Hyperledger Indy similar to zero knowledge proof (ZKP)?

Tags: hyperledger-indy

Is anonymous credentials in Hyperledger Indy similar to zero knowledge proof (ZKP)?

https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-anoncreds

Nathan Aw

Answer (score 1):

Yes! /indy-anoncreds are a type of ZKP based upon the [Idemix protocol](http://domino.research.ibm.com/library/cyberdig.nsf/papers/EEB54FF3B91C1D648525759B004FBBB1/%24File/rz3730_revised.pdf).

In [Anonymous credentials](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-anoncreds/blob/master/docs/anoncred-usecase1.pdf), by Dmitry Khovratovich, it is explained:

> We say that credentials are *unlinkable* if it is impossible to correlate the presented credential across multiple presentations. Technically it is implemented by the Prover *proving* with a zero-knowledge proof *that he has a credential* rather than showing the credential.

See [/awesome-indy#IDEMix-ZKP-](https://github.com/infominer33/awesome-decentralized-id/tree/master/awesome-indy#idemix-zkp-) for more information

Answer (score 0):

The credentials generated in Hyperledger Indy are verifiable credentials. It is powered by Identity Mixers. Another interesting feature in revocable credentials which is a important addition to the older implementation of identity mixers.